# Make border-radius greater than half of height

Tags: react-native, border

I want to make a "rounded bottom" component, without using a `ImageBackground`, like this:
[image]

I tried to use a combination of `<LinearGradient/>`, but to simplify the code in this question, I used `<View/>` instead.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={classes.container}>
        <View style={classes.block} />
        <View style={classes.roundedBlock} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const classes = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  block: {
    height: 135,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  roundedBlock: {
    height: 15,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2,
    borderBottomRightRadius: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2,
  }
})
```

This code is available for tests purpose on [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@pye/Ym90dG)

Here is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the borderRadius is **limited** to 7.5px, which is **half of the height of the block, instead of half of the width** as demanded.

Is there a way to override this limit? If no, is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ART` from `react-native` to draw whatever you want to draw. Some unofficial docs https://github.com/react-native-china/react-native-ART-doc/blob/master/doc.md. Please check the [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@troublediehard/bottom-rounded-block) or code below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, View, ART } from 'react-native';

const {
  Surface,
  Shape,
  Path,
  RadialGradient,
  Pattern,
  Transform,
  LinearGradient,
} = ART;
const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  getPathRect = () => {
    const x = width;
    const y = 0;
    const radius = 1000;

    return ART.Path()
      .moveTo(x, y)
      .lineTo(x - width, y)
      .lineTo(x - width, y + width / 2)
      .lineTo(x, y + width / 2)
      .close();
  };

  getPathArc = () => {
    const x = width;
    const y = 0;
    const radius = 1000;
    return ART.Path()
      .moveTo(x, y + width / 2)
      .arc(-x, 0, radius, radius)
      .close();
  };

  gradient = () => {
    return new LinearGradient(
      {
        '.01': 'blue', // blue in 1% position
        '1': 'red', // opacity white in 100% position
      },
      '0',
      '0',
      width,
      '0'
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={classes.container}>
        <Surface width={width} height={width}>
          <Shape
            d={this.getPathRect()}
            fill={this.gradient()}
            // stroke="red"
            strokeWidth="1"
            strokeCap="butt"
            strokeJoin="bevel"
          />
          <Shape
            d={this.getPathArc()}
            fill={this.gradient()}
            // stroke="red"
            strokeWidth="1"
            strokeCap="butt"
            strokeJoin="bevel"
          />
        </Surface>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const classes = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 30,
  },
});
```

Comment: @pistou just updated my answer to add gradient as fill color.

Comment: I was doing the same on my side, I figured out the params for the gradient, and I modified the [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@pye/Ym90dG) to fit my needs.